# Elaboration of infinite, finite and enumerable definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am starting to learn some of the basic concepts of math. The concept I am learning now is infinite, finite, and denumerable. I am having trouble understanding the book's definiton. I am hoping if someone can elaborate what it exactly means. The book states:

> A set $B$ is finite if it is empty or if there is a one-one function
>   with domain $B$ and range in an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$. If
>   there is no such function, the set is infinite. If there is a one-one
>   function with domain $B$ and range equal to all of $\mathbb{N}$, then
>   the set $B$ is denumerable (or enumerable). If a set is either finite
>   or denumerable, it is said to be countable.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @manu-fatto lol "I am hoping if someone can elaborate what it exactly means." I do not know what the defintion is telling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is the definition of a finite set;

"one-one function with domain B  and range in an initial segment of $\mathbb{N} $" just means that you can write the elements of your set in a list, one entry on each line, using n lines only, where n is  natural number.

So if your set is {2,3,4}, you write 2 on the first line, 3 on the second and 4 on the third line. Now 2 becomes the first element in your set even though it's the second natural number, because we put it on the first line. 
You don't ever skip lines in the construction of the list so the image will always be an intial segment of $\mathbb{N}$

An infinite set;

"If there is no such function, the set is infinite" If you can't write your set out on n lines, where n is a natural number then it is said to be infinite. Something like the decimal expansion of $\pi$ is said to be infinite.

A countable set;

"a one-one function with domain B  and range equal to all of N , then the set B  is denumerable" This means you can create a function that will write out all the elements of your set in a list. You can talk about your set having a first element, a second element and so on even if it has infinitely many elements. Think of the even numbers $2\mathbb{N}$ = {2,4,6...}. Our bijection is n/2. Take any number in $2\mathbb{N}$, half it, and whatever number you get you put it on that line in your list.

For an example of a set that is uncountable see the proof that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't countable, where one shows you can't write out all its elements in a list(or give a function to do so).

Comment: Thanks a lot! A couple of questions. Can you elaborate when you said "Think of the even numbers $2N  = {2,4,6...}$. Our bijection is $n/2$. Take any number in $2N$, half it, and whatever number you get you put it on that line in your list." Why is it countable again and why is $n/2$ the bijection?

Comment: Also, let us have a subset N denoted by $\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6,8,10\},\{2,3,...,100\}$. Why would this be considered finite? Is it finite just because it stops at the end?

Comment: if we have a bijection between two things (like here) we can say they are isomorphic, and this means they have a "degree of sameness" this includes countability. so all the bijection really does in this case is to show the same set in a new light, so that its countability is apparent.

Comment: the n/2 is the bijection because it is a simple formula to send the even numbers to the natural numbers. {2,4,6...} $\rightarrow$ {1,2,3...}

Comment: If N = {{1,3,5}, {2,4,5,8,10}, {2,3,...,100}} then it only has three elements(its elements are sets), so it is finite. If N one of the three sets mentioned, then it's easy to see what its cardinality is; say if N is {2,4,6,8,10}, then N has 5 elements, again finite. I'm not certain which of these two choices your N is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-to-one function $f\colon A \to B$ with range $B$ you have what is also called a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Intuitively we would say that in that case the two sets have *the same quantity of elements*. The definition of your book says that a set is finite if it has a bijection with one of the set:
$$
  \{\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,3,4\}...
$$
For example the set $\{2,4,6,8\}$ has a bijection with $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and hence is finite. If a set has a bijection with $\mathbb N$ then it is denumerable. This means that you can count all the elements of your set using natural numbers, but you will never stop.

Comment: Why exactly does the set $\{2,4,6,8\}$ have a bijection with $\{1,2,3,4\}$? Is it just because of the quantity? It doesn't matter what the set contains?

Comment: The function $f(n) = n/2$ is a bijection in this case.

Comment: A *bijection* is exactly what you need to define the concept of *same quantity*.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Lets have a subset $\mathbb{N}$ denoted by $\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6,8,10\},\{2,3,...,100\}$. Why would this be considered finite? They are not initial seqments of $\mathbb{N}$ which the definition says it has to be so they cant be finite cant they?

Comment: *which the definition says it has to be*... ?? Please read the definition again.

Comment: Have you understood why {2,4,6,8} is finite? The same is true with your examples.

Comment: Wikipedia might help giving another take...

Comment: @manu-fatto Yes I do. For my example that I gave why is that finite? "if there is a one-one function with domain B  and range in an initial segment of N" that part of the definition says initial segment or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: You gave three sets, or do you mean the union of them? Anyway all of them are finite. You understood correctly: the target of the function is an initial segmente of $\mathbb N$, but the domain is your set $B$